# Does the browser cache evict existing entries after a successful PUT/POST/DELETE?

Tags: http, caching, browser

If I send a GET xhr from the browser and the response comes with the correct headers, then the resource is stored in the cache. But I was wondering what would happen if I then send a PUT to the same url. Is the browser smart enough to know that this method will change the resource and so evict the entry from the cache?

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the [rfc](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.4):

> A cache MUST invalidate the effective Request URI (Section 5.5 of
> [RFC7230]) as well as the URI(s) in the Location and Content-Location
> response header fields (if present) when a non-error status code is
> received in response to an unsafe request method.

The unsafe methods include PUT/POST/DELETE, so browsers should evict the entries after requests with these methods are successful (status code 2xx or 3xx).

Though one should be aware that a resource can change even if no requests that modify it are made.